# Bash : How should I allow a user to be able to gunzip a file but not able to delete it?

Tags: bash, gzip, chmod

I have a list of gz files which i want to open up for multiple users with the following constraints :

1. Users are allowed to gzip/gunzip the files
2. Users are not allowed to delete the files
3. Users are not allowed to copy files to any other folder

any combination of chmod flags that can help out ? Any other bash commands are also welcome.

Comment: Probably not. Part of this depends on whether you are *giving* them the files (say, as an e-mail attachment) or simply providing them read access to files in a file system you both have access to. If you are asking about the files *produced* by unzipping an archive: they are created by the user, so you have no control over what the user does with them.

Comment: they can unzip the file, but they cannot copy the files produced to another folder. I want to give them read access with gunzip allowed.

Comment: You can't do that; *they* are creating the files when they unzip the archive, and can do whatever they want with the resulting files.